# Bloomberg API how to get only the latest quote to a given time specified by the user in Python?

Tags: python, api, quote, bloomberg

I need to query from the BBG API the nearest quote to 14:00 o'clock for a number of FX currency pairs. I read the developers guide and I can see that reference data request provides you with the latest quote available for a currency however if I run the request at 14.15 it will give me the nearest quote to that time not 14.00. Historical and intraday data output too many values as I need only the latest quote to a given time.

Would you be able to advise me if there is a type of request which will give me what I am looking for.

Comment: nearest before or after 14:00? You could request a 1-minute bar from 13:59 to 14:00 and take its closing value or a 1-minute bar from 14:00 to 14:01 and use its open value.

Comment: I need the nearest quote before 14:00 regardless of what time I run the query.

Comment: Then you can request tick data between 13:59 and 14:01 and find the nearest quote. Alternatively, you could use a time-based ticker such as `EURUSD L140 Crncy` and request the last price to get the 2pm (London time) quote for that pair.

Answer (score 0):

Further to previous suggestions, you can start subscription to //blp/mktdata service before 14:00 for each instrument to receive stream of real-time ticks. Cache the last tick, when hitting 14:00 mark the cache as pre-14:00, then mark the first tick after as post:14, select the nearest to 14:00 from both.